# Using virtualenv against custom Python binary installation on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, abaqus

ABAQUS is a finite element modelling package, and part of the installation is a more-or-less complete version of python 2.6.2. I want to use virtualenv to set up an environment where I can:

1. Import all of the ABAQUS python libraries
2. Use pip to access the wide world of python libraries (matplotlib especially)

I am running ubuntu 14.04 with virtualenv 1.11.6 installed, and I'm trying to interface with ABAQUS 6.13-2

When I try to set-up the virtualenv the following happens:

```
mark@hal:~/foo$ virtualenv -p /usr/local/simulia/6.13-2/tools/SMApy/python2.6/bin/python ENV
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/simulia/6.13-2/tools/SMApy/python2.6/bin/python
New python executable in ENV/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command /home/mark/foo/ENV/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/lo      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_v
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_v      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_v
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_v      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_v
  File "/usr/local/simulia/6.13-2/tools/SMApy/python2.6/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 10, in         from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: /home/mark/foo/ENV/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_A    ----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2338, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 824, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 992, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 960, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 902, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/mark/foo/ENV/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setupt
mark@hal:~/foo$
```

how can I fix this and set up a virtualenv using the python which came with abaqus?

Thanks.

In response to some of the comments below:

```
mark@hal:/usr/local/simulia/6.13-2$ which virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

Unfortunately neither virtualenv or pip ship with ABAQUS' python installation:

```
mark@hal:/usr/local/simulia/6.13-2$ find -name 'pip'
mark@hal:/usr/local/simulia/6.13-2$ find -name 'virtualenv'
```

What happens if I try and install pip in ABAQUS' python?

```
mark@hal:~/src/python/pip$ /usr/local/simulia/6.13-2/tools/SMApy/python2.6/bin/python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 17474, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 17466, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 17406, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "/tmp/tmpy6Dihu/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpy6Dihu/pip.zip/pip/log.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpy6Dihu/pip.zip/pip/backwardcompat/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/simulia/6.13-2/tools/SMApy/python2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 91, in <module>
    import hashlib
  File "/usr/local/simulia/6.13-2/tools/SMApy/python2.6/lib/python2.6/hashlib.py", line 136, in <module>
    md5 = __get_builtin_constructor('md5')
  File "/usr/local/simulia/6.13-2/tools/SMApy/python2.6/lib/python2.6/hashlib.py", line 63, in __get_builtin_constructor
    import _md5
ImportError: No module named _md5
```

It seems the _md5 module isn't even built-into their python.

Comment: I think here the problem is that `virtualenv` itself should be installed under the ABAQUS Python installation. I am not sure if the current virtualenv command you are using (check with `which virtualenv`) can get the system library paths right, thus failing.

Comment: You see it is falling back to system Python installation in `/usr/local/lib/` of which binaries are not probably compatible with ABAQUS binaries. This is probably because `virtualenv` needs `pip` from somewhere. And you can see this is Python 2.7, not Python 2.6 what you want.

Comment: Try installing using the target python from the beginning: `/usr/local/simulia/6.13-2/tools/SMApy/python2.6/bin/python virtualenv ENV`.